# will the new Outlook (One Outlook) replace Outlook or Windows Mail?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm quite confused about the announcement that Outlook will be replaced by "New Outlook"

[Microsoft always talks about "New Outlook"](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/outlook-blog/things-to-know-about-the-new-outlook-for-windows/ba-p/3383964) wheras many other sources talk about "One Outlook" replacing "Windows Mail".
[See also here](https://insider.microsoft365.com/en-us/blog/new-outlook-for-windows-available-to-all-office-insiders) for an announcment from Microsoft or [concerns from VSTO-Plugin developers](https://portal.microfocus.com/s/article/KM000018799?language=en_US)

It seems all very unclear to me and, if look at comments from the first link above, many others.

Will the current Outlook with all its features like (Tasks, Appointments, VSTO-support) be replaced by this new Outlook or will Outlook and this New Outlook (whatever it may be called) coexist as different products?

Does any one have clearer information?

Comment: This is an opinion question. Microsoft would like us all to use Web Apps. But at a Seminar in Redmond (Microsoft) they were not close in providing all the features.

Comment: I think both will be replaced. Microsoft wants to replace Windows Mail, and I already have seen this new One Outlook when trying out the new outlook, which is in essence the web app in a shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for Windows Mail(,Calendar and People Apps), new Windows 11 devices will be shipped with the new Outlook for Windows by default starting from 2024. Maybe this represents the "replacement"?
Reference: [Outlook for Windows: The Future of Mail, Calendar and People on Windows 11](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/outlook-for-windows-the-future-of-mail-calendar-and-people-on-windows-11-715fc27c-e0f4-4652-9174-47faa751b199).
[image]

When it comes to the classic version of Outlook, I haven't seen any official article explicitly stating whether or when it will be replaced by the New Outlook. My personal opinion is that, considering that the classic Outlook has much richer functionalities than the New Outlook at this point of time, even if MS does have the plan to retire the old Outlook, this will take a quite loooooong time until most essential features are implemented into the New Outlook. (As indicated in [this blog](https://insider.microsoft365.com/en-us/blog/starting-to-support-third-party-accounts-in-new-outlook-for-windows-preview#:%7E:text=In%20addition%20to%20continuing%20to%20address%20your%20feedback%20and%20requests%20as%20they%20come%20in%2C%20we%20are%20working%20on%3A%C2%A0%C2%A0), the New Outlook is still being improved based on users' feedback and feature requests. )

And as regards to the VSTO-support, according to the following article, there's no plan **at this time** to add it to the New Outlook, “but the investments to enrich the Web Add-in platform to offer similar capabilities will continue. ”
[Things to know about the new Outlook for Windows](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/outlook-blog/things-to-know-about-the-new-outlook-for-windows/ba-p/3383964#:%7E:text=*There%20is%20no%20plan%20to%20support%20COM/VSTO%20Add%2Dins%20at%20this%20point%2C%20but%20the%20investments%20to%20enrich%20the%20Web%20Add%2Din%20platform%20to%20offer%20similar%20capabilities%20will%20continue.%20Please%20share%20any%20outstanding%20gaps%20here.).